# Decode SSL packets in WireShark

Tags: ssl, wireshark

I have `cert.cer`, base64 x509 and a Wireshark dump in `.pcap` format.

The packets are encoded, so how do I decode them?

Now:

```
[site-ip],443,http,xe.cer
```

but it's still not working.

Comment: Why would you want to decode SSL encrypted packets?  Unless you're trying to steal encrypted information, this is highly unorthodox.

Comment: If she has the certificate I wouldn't say it's a theaft. Is Wireshark am evil software because it supports this option?